# Issue: Updating Elements within HTML Code Template using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, innerhtml

I'm having trouble updating elements using this technique.

I'm pretty new to Angular, maybe there is a better work-around?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdpNxB

```
function ctrlSizing($scope) {
    $scope.item = {
        name: '',
        job: '',
        email: '',
        mobile: '',
        office: '',
    };

    $scope.$watch('item', function(value) {
        console.debug(value);
        $scope.code = document.getElementById('code_html').innerHTML();

        var err = function() {
            $scope.code = '' + $scope.item.name + '!';
        };
    };
}
```

Comment: innerHTML is not a method, it's a string property.

Comment: it should be done in controller though it would be `document.getElementById('code_html')[0].innerHTML`

Comment: can you explain better the issue you are facing?

Comment: post full code and problem, but from what i see you did not get point for what is angular ... especially getting values from innerHTML when you have ng-models ....